# What's the difference between dic[key] and [dic objectforkey:key]?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What's the difference between dic[key] and [dic objectforkey:key]?

I'm so confuse about it . 
And which function is the best way in objective-c development.

Comment: None. They're the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first way of subscripting dictionaries and `NSArray`s [will not work prior to Xcode 4.4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode#4.x_series); the second one will. Other than that, there's no difference: it's a "compiler trick" that transforms the new syntax into the old method call.